# Adding a function (filter?) score to a query with elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch, search, elasticsearch-plugin, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm struggling to get a query to work with elasticsearch where I'm combining a multi_match query with *field boosting*, *field_value_factors*, and then a function that should boost any documents matching a particular document type.

The query works flawlessly except for when I add in the function clause in the second query which errors with the following:

**you can either define [functions] array or a single function, not both. already found [field_value_factor], now encountering [functions]**

To be clear...

*My goal is to boost any documents containing the field "doctype" matching the term "html" by a factor of 10 using the 'functions' block below*

**This Works**

```
$param = json_encode(
        array(
            "query" => array(
                "function_score" => array(
                    "query" => array(
                        "multi_match" => array(
                            "query" => $query,
                            "fields" => array("title^5","body"),
                            "fuzziness" => 1
                        )
                    ),
                    "field_value_factor" => array(
                        "field" => "hits",
                        "modifier" => "log1p",
                        "factor" => 10
                    ),
                    "field_value_factor" => array(
                        "field" => "weight",
                        "modifier" => "log1p",
                        "factor" => 3
                    )
                )
            ),
            "size" => $offset,
            "from" => $start
        )
    );
```

**Adding the following clause to the second query does not work**

```
"functions" => [array("filter" => array("term" => array("doctype" => "html")), "boost_factor" => 10)],
                    "max_boost" => 10,
                    "boost_mode" => "multiply"
```

** Full query - this doesn't work **

```
$param = json_encode(
        array(
            "query" => array(
                "function_score" => array(
                    "query" => array(
                        "multi_match" => array(
                            "query" => $query,
                            "fields" => array("title^5","body"),
                            "fuzziness" => 1
                        )
                    ),
                    "field_value_factor" => array(
                        "field" => "hits",
                        "modifier" => "log1p",
                        "factor" => 10
                    ),
                    "field_value_factor" => array(
                        "field" => "weight",
                        "modifier" => "log1p",
                        "factor" => 3
                    ),
                    "functions" => [
                        array("filter" => array("term" => array("doctype" => "html")), "boost_factor" => 10)
                    ],
                    "max_boost" => 10,
                    "boost_mode" => "multiply"
                )
            ),
            "size" => $offset,
            "from" => $start
        )
    );
```

Comment: What does _does not work_ mean?  Errors? No records returned?

Comment: @AbraCadaver - There is an error... **you can either define [functions] array or a single function, not both. already found [field_value_factor], now encountering [functions]**

Comment: I'm not sure, but try removing the `[ ]` from around the functions array.